# Thymeleaf selected option выбор по умолчанию

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

Проект Spring-Boot + Thymeleaf
Имеется две сущности
People и Children

```
@Entity
public class People {
    
    @Id
    private Long id;
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Children children;
}
@Entity
public class Children {
    
    @Id
    private Long id;
    private String name;
}
```

В форме ввода есть поле выбора Children.
Все работает, вот только не могу сделать, чтобы при загрузке формы там по умолчанию ни чего не было выбрано или что-то типа "---":

```html
<select class="custom-select" id="inputGroupSelect02" th:field="*{people.id}">
  <option th:each="children : ${childrenList}"
  th:value="${children.id}"
  th:text="${children.name}"/>
</select>
```

Перепробовал много вариантов, которые нашел на этом и на других форумах:

```
<option selected>Choose...</option>
<option value="" selected="selected">selected</option>
<option selected="">selected ...</option>
```

все время вылетает с ошибкой в этой строке:
" Attribute "value" is required in "option" tags"

Comment: По умолчанию есть выбор, потому что вы пишите th:value="...". То что указано в value и является выбором по умолчанию, просто не пишите этот атрибут

Comment: Если я не пишу этот атрибут, то по умолчанию у меня выбран первый из моего списка. А мне надо, чтобы было выбрано пустое поле или что-то типа "---"

Comment: тогда создай пустой элемент, который будет первым в списке и будет выбран по умолчанию

Comment: Ничего не выбрано это "-1"